# Matching rules varies at run time

Tags: c#, algorithm, dynamic, compare, runtime

I have these two C# objects, which has some properties exposed

```
class A{
prop1,prop2, prop3, producttype
} 

class B{
prop10, prop11, prop12, prop13, productype
}
```

Depending upon the product type, at run time, the matching algorithm would change. 
Example,

```
if (A.productType =="ABC")
    then match this logic, A.prop1 == B.prop10 && A.prop3 == B.prop12

if (A.productType=="DEF") 
    then match this logic A.pro1 == B.prop11

//and many more
```

How to write such logic cleanly and reusable? Is there any design pattern which I can use?

Comment: Whats the relation between the statements? If you do not have a relation, which may help you construct an algorithm to use maybe delegates, or generics then you may as well write the statements yourself. Simply asking, what is the matching algorithm you are talking about.

Comment: The matching algorithm varies according to the productType, so when the product type is "ABC", you go and equate these properties, if "DEF", match with other properties, and so on. I want to write it cleanly and future proofing for other product types in future.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look into the [Strategy Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern). You won't be able to get around some `if/else` blocks to pick the correct strategy though, unless you can abstract the rules by which you pick the strategy.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @Hrqls This is a legitimate answer, perhaps even a good one (I'm not familiar with many design patterns and can't vote accurately here).  This answer the question directly and also provides a link for further reading.